# Difference between these 2 promises syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am quite confused between these two ways of returning the promises, could someone please explain the difference? I tried to find some whereabouts on google, but couldn't find the exact match.

```
var a = Promise.resolve('foo');
return a.then();
```

vs

```
return Promise.resolve('foo').then();
```

Comment: Edited what was almost certainly a typo.

Comment: They are totally same

Comment: A value can be stored in an intermediate variable but it doesn't need to. `var foo = 42; return foo + 1;` and `return 42 + 1;` have the same outcome.

Comment: by the way, `return a.then();` == `return a;` - I'm assuming you don't actually do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing promise specific about this.

```
return a.b();
```

Is the same as:

```
var c = a;
return c.b();
```

In this case `a` is `Promise.resolve('foo')`.